# Django all-auth maybe does not support the latest django version 2.01. In that case, How i can use django all-auth into the latest django version

Tags: python, django-allauth, django-2.0

Django all-auth maybe does not support the latest Django version 2.01. In that case, How i can use Django all-auth into the latest django version. Any idea when they will launch the latest version of Django allauth.
TIA

Comment: What did you find about all-auth not supporting django 2.0 ? can you provide a code snippet where django-allauth is not working with Django 2.0

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
] In version 2 can i use this or should i modify to 'path'.  How to deal with this?

Comment: System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern '^login/' [name='account_login'] has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().
?: (2_0.W001) Your URL pattern '^signup/$' [name='account_signup'] has a route that contains '(?P<', begins with a '^', or ends with a '$'. This was likely an oversight when migrating to django.urls.path().------------------------------this is what my PC shows me.